# Can I assign a function in php

Tags: php, function, functional-programming

I want to know if I can assign a function.

I have a function call `mpurl($s, $pagevar, $pages)`, this function call occurs many times in my code. now I want to add more cases for this function. like:

```
if(strpos($s, 'sign') !== false) {
    mpurl($s, $pagevar, $pages);
} else {
    my_mpurl($s, $pagevar, $pages);
}
```

I don't want to use this if-else in every invoke of function mpurl, so I want to change the meaning of function mpurl globally.

So here the question comes, Can I write like this:

```
if(strpos($s, 'sign') === false) {
    mpurl = my_mpurl;
}
mpurl($s, $pagevar, $pages);
```

or how can I implement this purpose? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update*
Recap of the answer below. If both functions take the same arguments, in the same order, you can simply use variable functions:

```
if (strpos($s, 'sign') === false) {
    $func = 'my_mpurl';
} else {
    $func = 'mpurl';
}
$func($s, $pagevar, $pages);
```

If, for some reason you can't upgrade and are stuck with an older version, you can use `call_user_func_array`:

```
if (strpos($s, 'sign') === false) {
    $func = 'my_mpurl';
} else {
    $func = 'mpurl';
}
call_user_func_array($func, array($s, $pagevar, $pages));
```

Naturally, you can use the `$func` var as much as you want/need to to call the function whenever you need.

---

So basically, depending on the value of some variable, you want to call a different function with the same arguments. That's what [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) is for:

```
if (strpos($s, 'sign') === false) {
    $func = 'my_mpurl';
} else {
    $func = 'mpurl';
}
call_user_func_array($func, array($a, $b, $c));
```

Same thing, but a tad shorter (and with the short array syntax):

```
$func = 'mpurl';
if (strpos($s, 'sign') === false)
    $func = 'my_'.$func;//prepend
call_user_func_array($func, [$s, $pagevar, $pages]);
//or even shorter
$func($s, $pagevar, $pages);
```

The variable-value as function name (variable function) syntax was introduced in PHP 5.3. If you're not running on 5.3 yet, you really ought to upgrade, but meanwhile, you can use `call_user_func_array`

Comment: Or you do `$func($a, $b, $c);` :-)

Comment: @jeroen: was just testing that, to make sure that was even possible, added it to my answer

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Great, I just tested `call_user_func_array`, it works. thank you so I don't need to modify other guy's code and can add new functions. It really helps.

Comment: @xcaptain: Try using `$func($s, $pagevar, $pages)`, too: if you're running PHP 5.3>=, that'd work, too and it's a hell of a lot cleaner than `call_user_func_array` is

Comment: @xcaptain: Pleas read the help section of this site: you're asked not to post _"Thank you"_ comments. Instead, the stack-overflow way of saying thanks is to accept the answer that helped you. If you don't know how to do this, [see this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), which explains it all. Accepting will give you +2 rep, to encourage accepting responses, so go over previous questions and mark some answers as accepted there, too

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem accepted your answer. But I found I can't use `$func = 'self::mpurl';` in a class. Hope for further infomations.

Comment: Variable functions do not require PHP 5.3. You're getting mixed up with closures. Variable functions worked in PHP 4 at least. Even if that weren't the case, `call_user_func` would be a better fit here than `call_user_func_array`.

Comment: @xcaptain: No, but you can use `$this->{$func}()`  in a non-static context, and probably `self::{$func}()` in a static call (will test the static call later, first I'll take a shower :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a switch inside the function. Which might look like:

```
function mpurl($a,$b,$c) {

    switch ($a) {
        case 'sign' : 
            // do some stuff
        break;
        default : 
            // do some other stuff
        break;
    }

    // do some common stuff in the function
}
```

Another possibility (based on your comment) could be as follows. In the case that `$a` is equal to 'sign', you stop executing the rest of the function and return the result immediately. If other cases, you keep executing the rest of the function.

```
function mpurl($a,$b,$c) {

    switch ($a) {
        case 'sign' : 
            // do some stuff 
            return $result;
        break;
        default : 
            // do some other stuff
        break;
    }

    // do some common stuff in the function
}
```

Comment: I don't want to modify this function, I want to define a new function. Because the function `mpurl` is very long, and my `my_mpurl` can be very short.

Comment: @xcaptain So call `my_mpurl` from within the switch or use a 3rd function to determine which function to call.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reassign a function like that. The best you can do is encapsulate the if-else in a helper function:

```
function mpurlx($s, $pagevar, $pages) {
    if (strpos($s, 'sign') !== false) {
        mpurl($s, $pagevar, $pages);
    } else {
        my_mpurl($s, $pagevar, $pages);
    }
}
```

Then do a search & replace on the other code so it calls the helper function everywhere.

Comment: Hope someday php will support function rename.

Comment: @xcaptain That sounds horrible and confusing.